# Integration test for server

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, server, integration-testing

I have server that should perform some job before start, and log about success. For example:

```
const http = require('http');

function startServer() {
    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.write('hello\n');
        res.end();
    }).listen(3000);
    console.log('server is ready');
}

//as 'job' we will use timer
setTimeout(startServer, 10000);
```

I need create integration tests that will check:

1. log contains information about server is ready
2. request/response work correct

## Questions:

- Should I run server for every test case or enough single instance?
- Job before start server takes some time.
  How I know when need send
  request? I cannot rely on log since in this case second test will
  dependent on result of first one.

Comment: why not to use async-await ??

Comment: If you reuse a component instance between tests there is a risk of one test polluting the results of another test that reuses the same component.  If you do not reuse a component, then you may incur additional time setting up and tearing down each test. *You* get to weigh the pros and cons and make your own decision about what you "should" do.

Comment: For your second question, include an orchestrating component owned by the testing framework that is common to both client and server.  Have the server notify the orchestrator when it reaches a listening state.  Have the client wait for the orchestrator to tell it it is an appropriate time to submit a request.

Answer (score 0):

Wyck, do you suggest using the observer pattern? Something like that:

```
describe('app', () => {
    let orchestrator;
    let process;

    beforeAll(() => {
        jest.setTimeout(50000);
        orchestrator = (function () {
            const listeners = [];
            let serverIsReady = false;
            return {
                addListener: fn => {
                    listeners.push(fn);
                    fn(serverIsReady);
                },
                setServerIsReady: status => {
                    serverIsReady = status;
                    listeners.forEach(item => item(status));
                },
            }
        })();
    });
    
    test('server is ready', done => {
        process = spawn('node', ['./app.js']);
        process.stdout.on('data', data => {
            expect(`${data}`).toContain('server is ready');
            orchestrator.setServerIsReady(true);
            done();
        });
    });

    test('server return response', done => {
        orchestrator.addListener(serverIsReady => {
            if (serverIsReady) {
                http.get('http://localhost:3000', res => {
                    res.on('data', chunk => {
                        expect(`${chunk}`).toContain('hello');
                        done();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```